# Remove all strings within parenthesis in a filename in a directory including parenthesis

Tags: python-3.x

1. I have 5 files which are manually downloaded into a folder on my desktop everyday
2. Since they are downloaded, windows adds the (n) at the end of each file. I.e. File1 (12) File2 (12)
3. I want to replace the end parenthesis with the date it is downloaded. I.e. File1 11.22.19 File2. 11.22.19

Any idea how?

Tried the following and a replace function but have not worked well.

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("path"):
        if filename.endswith(".csv") or filename.endswith(".xslx") or filename.endswith (".xls"):
                result = filename.find[("(")+1:s.find(")")]

                newname = filename[:result] + ".xlsx"

                print (newname)

                os.rename(filename,newname)
```

Comment: What have you tried? The modules you need are `os` for file manipulation, and `re` for search and replace stuff.

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: What does "has not worked well" mean? What did it do, and how was it different from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this approach would work:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.now() # get today's date
date = str(date.day) + '.' + str(date.month) + '.' + str(date.year)

import os
names = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'] # names of files to replace

os.chdir('Downloads') # path to downloads
files = os.listdir() # get files in directory
found = []

for file in files: # filter unwanted files
    check = [name in file for name in names]
    if any(check):
        found.append(file)

for file in found:
    openbracket = file.find('(') # locate the brackets
    closebracket = file.find(')') + 1
    if openbracket and closebracket: # replace brackets and rename
        os.rename(file, file.replace(file[openbracket:closebracket], date))
```